# How to pattern match head and tail types of a scala list?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to `pattern match` on different segments of a `list` in `scala` on the types of the `head` and `tail`:

```
class Solution07 extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  "plain recursive flatten" should "flatten a list" in {
    val list1 = List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))
    val list1Flattened = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)

    flattenRecur(list1) should be (list1Flattened)
  }

  def flattenRecur(ls: List[Any]): List[Int] = ls match {
    case (head: Int) :: (tail: List[Any]) => head :: flattenRecur(tail)
    case (head: List[Int]) :: (tail: List[Any]) => head.head :: flattenRecur(head.tail :: tail)
    case (head: List[Any]) :: (tail: List[Any]) => flattenRecur(head) :: flattenRecur(tail) // non-variable type... on this line.
  }
}
```

I get:

> Error:(18, 17) non-variable type argument Int in type pattern
>   List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is
>   eliminated by erasure
>       case (head: List[Int]) :: (tail: List[Any]) => head.head :: flattenRecur(head.tail :: tail)
>                   ^

What am I missing? how is it possible for me to pattern match on the `head` and `tail`'s **types** of the list?

Comment: try replace `case (head: List[Int]) :: (tail: List[Any]) => ` with `case ( (headhead : Int) :: (headtail : List[Any]) ) :: (tail : List[Any]) =>` That would allow you to fight type erasure

Comment: The issue is for line `case (head: List[Any]) :: (tail: List[Any])` you have mentioned a different line, is that supposed to help that line as well???

Comment: the third choice conflicts with the second. So you could adjust either the second choice or the third choice. Since the third choice is more general, it's easier to made the second more specific

Comment: are you claiming that I don't need the third case: `case (head: List[Any]) :: (tail: List[Any])` because its conflicting?

Comment: I suppose that all choices are needed for some of your functionality. You should not discard either.The issue is with scala's type erasure, that could not distinct the second and the third choice. So you should expand the second choice more to make types distinctive. For scala pattern matching all types List[blabla] is the same. But you could get head of List and specify type for it. And that type would be checked correctly. In the second choice the `head` is of type List[Int] that lacks description. So you should expand `head` further to `headhead :: headtail`. Now scala would catch types

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that @Andreas solution with HList is a nice example for solving the problem, but I still do not understand what's the problem with this:

```
 def flatten(ls: List[_]): List[Int] = ls match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case (a: Int) :: tail => a :: flatten(tail)
    case (a: List[_]) :: tail => flatten(a) ::: flatten(tail)
    case _ :: tail => flatten(tail)
  }
```

Then:

```
println(flatten(List(List("one",9,8),3,"str",4,List(true,77,3.2)))) // List(9, 8, 3, 4, 77)
```

I don't see any problems with type erasure in your task, because you actually don't need to test the types that are erased. I've intentionally skipped all erased types in my example - to show this. Type erasure does not clear the type information of the elements of the list, it clears only the type information of list generic which you have `Any` or `_` in my case - so you do not need that at all. If I am not missing someting, in your example the types are not erased at all, because you anyway have `Any` almost everywhere.

Comment: you are right with this observation :) should I adapt the answer ?

Comment: Maybe, I'd just remove the statement about type erasure. I think the proposal of using `HList` is a good alternative, but I don't think it's the only option - you can easily live without it.

Comment: And I should probably mention that I haven't used shapeless yet, so I am not authority in deciding whether it is good approach

Comment: adapted and type inference paragraph removed

Answer (score 1):

You are hit by restrictions given by the object system:

The only common parent for `List[Int]` and `Int` is `Any`

So due to that  the inference system can only safely assume that you could return `Any`. The solution proposed @jwvh is doable but has a possible danger of runtime exceptions.

If you want to solve the problem in a typesafe way an option could be to use `HList` of the shapeless library https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless : https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists

Comment: Could you please look at my example in the answer below?  I don't think (2) is true - the sequence knows about the types of the elements that are inside. It doesn't know only of it's `T` which is not needed for the task. I agree `HList` are great and they are one of the possible options how to solve this, but this is not the only option

Comment: For your extended answer this is completely right. The type erasure does not affect you.