# Scala: recursively pattern match a heterogeneous list, obtaining the correct type of each element

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming, shapeless

I am trying to do something like below, that is, process an `HList` recursively by pattern matching the head & tail, each time passing the head to a generic function.

```
import shapeless._
trait MyTrait {

  def myFunc[T](x: String => T): Boolean

  def iter(myHList: HList, acc: List[Boolean]): List[Boolean] = {
    myHList match {
      case HNil => acc
      case head :: tail => myFunc(head) :: iter(tail, acc)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the head that I get from matching is of type `Any` rather than the type of what I put into the `HList`.  I want the function that takes head as an argument to have the correct type parameter `T`.

Is this possible?  Maybe with some other means besides Shapeless?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115045/how-to-pattern-match-head-and-tail-types-of-a-scala-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pattern match head and tail types of a scala list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115045/how-to-pattern-match-head-and-tail-types-of-a-scala-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Map be performed on a Scala HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349482/can-map-be-performed-on-a-scala-hlist)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def iter(myHList: HList, acc: List[Boolean]): List[Boolean] = {
  (myHList: @unchecked) match {
    case HNil => acc
    case (head: Function1[String, _] @unchecked) :: tail => 
      myFunc(head) :: iter(tail, acc)
  }
}
```

(the first `@unchecked` suppresses warning that pattern matching is not exhaustive, the second `@unchecked` suppresses warning about unchecked generic `String` because of type erasure).

Alternatively you can match more type-safely. But normally writing that an argument is just an `HList` rather than specific `A :: B :: ... :: HNil` is too rough. Since your function acts differently on values of different types (namely, `HNil` and `H :: T`) it's a `Poly`.

```
object iter extends Poly2 {
  implicit val nilCase: Case.Aux[HNil, List[Boolean], List[Boolean]] = 
    at((_, acc) => acc)

  implicit def consCase[A, T <: HList](implicit 
    tailCase: Case.Aux[T, List[Boolean], List[Boolean]]
    ): Case.Aux[(String => A) :: T, List[Boolean], List[Boolean]] =
    at { case (head :: tail, acc) => myFunc(head) :: iter(tail, acc) }
}
```

Usage:

```
def myFunc[T](x: String => T): Boolean = true

iter(((s: String) => s.toUpperCase) :: ((s: String) => s.length) :: HNil, List[Boolean]()) 
// List(true, true)
```